# Substarct two float numbers in shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, bc

I have written shell script to substract two float values 
For eg. below are the two values :

```
debit_amount=7.853117806000353E7
credit_amount=3223649.619999993

val1=$(printf "%f", "$debit_amount")
val2=$(printf "%f", "$credit_amount")

echo " val1 = " $val1
echo " val2 = " $val2

final=`echo "$val1-$val2" |bc`
```

Output :

```
 val1 =  78531178.060004,
 val2 =  3223649.620000,
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

I got the above error. I tried below commands as well

```
final=$(echo "$val1 - $val2"|bc)
echo "$(($val1-$val2))"
echo `expr $val1 - $val2`
```

However I am still getting syntax error. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the commas in the `printf` calls:

```
val1=$(printf "%f" "$debit_amount")
val2=$(printf "%f" "$credit_amount")
```

It's not necessary to delimit the arguments by comma. That's why the input for `bc` looked like this:

```
78531178.060004,-3223649.620000,
```

which `bc` cannot interpret.

---

**BTW**: You should not use [the backticks (`` ` ``) anymore](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated):

```
final="$(echo "$val1 - $val2" | bc)"
```